# android navigation view badge on menu icon

Tags: android, android-menu, android-navigationview

I'm using Navigation view for slide drawer, and setting options using `app:menu` property. I want to show the notification count on Menu Icon.
I have specified `android:actionLayout` in menu xml, but it is showing the badge to the right of title but I want it on top right corner of the Icon.
My Code is like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main" />
```

main_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<group
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_notification"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_notfication"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_counter"
        android:title="Notification"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_setting"
        android:title="Settings"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_faq_help"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_faq"
        android:title="FAQ and Help"/>

    .
    .
    .       
</group>
```

menu_counter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_bagde"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="12"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

I want it like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can Customize NavigationView also.

Just use Code like below.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/drawer_layout"/>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Now in include tag, Add a layout with the recycler and in the recyclerView's onCreateView give the recycler the layout you want and set whatever values you want to set in onBind method like you do normally.

Just remember to call findViewById for recycler in navigationView like : navigationView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerVIew)

Comment: could you please provide some more details about how to use this method to achieve the poster's desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SublimeNavigationView](https://github.com/vikramkakkar/SublimeNavigationView) to do this.

if you don't want to use third party drawer then you can create Navigation Drawer with `RecyclerView` or `ListView` instead of `NavigationView`. and you can easily customize `RecyclerView` or `ListView`.

Comment: Could you provide a code example of how to do this? From what I can see, SublimeNavigationView supports badges to the right of menu items, but not over the icon, which is what the question asked for